push to array index and reduce index having same key
Please help me merge array's cities whereas the state is same and remove duplicate index. The expecting output is given below
Input array
[
    {
        "state": "delhi",
        "cities": "central delhi"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "dumka"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "deoghar"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "jasidih"
    },
    {
        "state": "karnataka",
        "cities": "bail hongal"
    },
    {
        "state": "ladakh",
        "cities": "kargil"
    }
]

I have tried multiple code but adding this one as i am still trying to get my desired output
arr1.map((row, index) => ({
    itemLabel: arr1.state,
    itemValue: arr1.cities - arr2[index].cities
}))

Need this output
[
    {
        "state": "delhi",
        "cities": "central delhi"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": ["dumka","deoghar","jasidih"]
    },
    {
        "state": "karnataka",
        "cities": "bail hongal"
    },
    {
        "state": "ladakh",
        "cities": "kargil"
    }
]


What is the expected result of "central delhi" - "kargil" or arr1.cities - arr2[index].cities?

You could group first and then map the cities.


const
    data = [{ state: "delhi", cities: "central delhi" }, { state: "jharkhand", cities: "dumka" }, { state: "jharkhand", cities: "deoghar" }, { state: "jharkhand", cities: "jasidih" }, { state: "karnataka", cities: "bail hongal" }, { state: "ladakh", cities: "kargil" }],
    result = Object
        .entries(Object.groupBy(data, ({ state }) => state))
        .map(([state, objects]) => ({ state, cities: objects.map(({ cities }) => cities) }));

console.log(result);




You can first use Object.groupBy to group all objects with the same state, then transform the result by mapping over its entries.


const arr = [
    {
        "state": "delhi",
        "cities": "central delhi"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "dumka"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "deoghar"
    },
    {
        "state": "jharkhand",
        "cities": "jasidih"
    },
    {
        "state": "karnataka",
        "cities": "bail hongal"
    },
    {
        "state": "ladakh",
        "cities": "kargil"
    }
];
const res = Object.entries(Object.groupBy(arr, o => o.state)).map(([state, els]) =>
   ({state, cities: els.length > 1 ? els.map(el => el.cities) : els[0].cities}));
console.log(res);




My suggestion:


const data = [{
    "state": "delhi",
    "cities": "central delhi"
  },
  {
    "state": "jharkhand",
    "cities": "dumka"
  },
  {
    "state": "jharkhand",
    "cities": "deoghar"
  },
  {
    "state": "jharkhand",
    "cities": "jasidih"
  },
  {
    "state": "karnataka",
    "cities": "bail hongal"
  },
  {
    "state": "ladakh",
    "cities": "kargil"
  }
];

// Group by state
const groupedData = Object.groupBy(data, item => item.state);

// Formatting the output
const result = Object.keys(groupedData).map(state => ({
  state,
  cities: [...new Set(groupedData[state].map(item => item.cities))] // Remove duplicates
}));

console.log(result);




This can be done by grouping the cities by state and merging the cities for states that appear multiple times,This can be done using JS reduce .


const arr1 = [
    { "state": "delhi", "cities": "central delhi" },
    { "state": "jharkhand", "cities": "dumka" },
    { "state": "jharkhand", "cities": "deoghar" },
    { "state": "jharkhand", "cities": "jasidih" },
    { "state": "karnataka", "cities": "bail hongal" },
    { "state": "ladakh", "cities": "kargil" }
];

const result = Object.values(arr1.reduce((acc, { state, cities }) => {
    if (!acc[state]) {
        acc[state] = { state, cities: [] };
    }
    if (Array.isArray(acc[state].cities)) {
        acc[state].cities.push(cities);
    } else {
        acc[state].cities = [cities];
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

result.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.cities.length === 1) {
        entry.cities = entry.cities[0];
    }
});

console.log(result);



